# getting SIGABRT while creating a Predicate

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my application, I am using `NSPredicate` to filter an array filled with data coming from iPhone's Addressbook.

For every person in the array, I get `firstName`,`lastName`,`email` and `nickName`,
and then I filter the array based on a search string,

I create a predicate for that `searchString`, but for some reason, which I can't figure out, my app is crashing.

I am new to Predicates and cannot figure out, where am I going wrong, my code was working fine with 'contains' instead of 'beginswith' ?

Here is the code snippet which crashes my app,

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                            @"(firstName beginswith[cd] %@) OR (lastName beginswith[cd] %@) OR (nickName beginswith[cd] %@) OR (email beginswith[cd] %@)",
                                            searchTextComponent,searchTextComponent,searchTextComponent];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 "%@" and only 3 arguments.

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                            @"(firstName beginswith[cd] %@) OR (lastName beginswith[cd] %@) OR (nickName beginswith[cd] %@) OR (email beginswith[cd] %@)",
                                            searchTextComponent,searchTextComponent,searchTextComponent, SEARCHTEXTCOMPONENT ONE MORE TIME];
```

Comment: Thanks, how stupid of me, BTW do I need to put these strings for whic i am checking beginswith, in signle quotes ?
like : '%@'

Comment: Its not crashing anymore, but my filtered array is coming out to be with zero elements.

Comment: anyways, got my problem sorted, thanks for trhe initial help though.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say I know much about using predicates myself. I just noticed the missing argument. I have only used predicates once, and I have used them with %@ (no single quotes).

Comment: yeah..I realized, I was using quotes and thats why nothing in the array was matching.